# How to Open a 5 File (.5) with Photoshop CS5

Tags: file, photoshop, file-format, file-conversion

I recently made a certificate in Photoshop CS6 and for some odd reason the file was saved as:

certificate (file type: .5)

Is there a ways that I can convert this file to a format that I can use in Photoshop? When I try to open the file using Photoshop it says:

"Could not complete your request because it is not the right kind of document."

The same happens when I try CS5 also. I need to be able to edit this file again in Photoshop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had file extensions hidden. I'm using a Windows 8 Operating System so to change that I had to:

Left Click File Explorer> Left Click "View" Tab> Check the box "File name extensions".

This makes it so I could view the extension at the end of the file name.

This allowed me to delete the (.5) to "certificate4.5", to add (.psd) "certificate4.psd"

It opened in CS6 perfectly and is editable.

Before when I had changed the end of the file name I couldn't delete the (.5) so it would do this: "certificate.5.psd" Making it a file that isn't recognized by anything (.5.psd).